# Reading from file into xml document and then saving xml document to file using powershell

Tags: powershell, character-encoding, xmldocument

I have a powershell script in which I am doing the following :

```
$FilePath = "Somepath"
#XPath = "Some Xpath"
$Attribute = "Delimiter"
$Value="&#x9;"
$xml=new-object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument 
$xml.Load($FilePath)
$a=$xml.selectSinglenode($XPath)
if ($a -eq $null) 
{
    throw "Cannot Load XPATH: $XPath from $FilePath"
}
if([system.string]::isnullorwhitespace($Attribute))
{
if (!($a.InnerXml -eq $Value)) 
{
    $a.InnerXml = $Value
}
} 
else 
{
if (!($a.($Attribute) -eq $Value))
{
    $a.($Attribute)= $Value
}
}       
$xml.Save($FilePath)
```

What is happening that the file being saved has the value of that attribute being saved as below

```
 <Element Delimiter="&amp;#x9;">
```

where I want it to be

```
 <Element Delimiter="&#x9;">
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You "could" use `-Replace` after creating the file. `(Get-Content -Path $FilePath) -Replace "&amp;","&" | Set-Content $FilePath`.

Comment: That will replace all such instances, but I just only want this to happen with an attribute in a single node.

Comment: Or it sounds like you're trying to save the file name based on attribute and he is saying that through using his code it'll save the file name with `&amp;` replaced with `&`

Comment: No, that is not the case. What I meant was if I had such a value Delimiter="&#x9;" in the attribute of a element in my xml file, and then I just open and save the file without any changes using xmldox.save(), it changes the Delimiter="&#x9;" to Delimiter="&amp;#x9;" which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting $Value to the string ampersand, pound-sign, lowercase x, digit 9. So, XML is dutifully encoding it as required.

Instead,

```
$Value=[char]0x0009
```

which is the single UTF-16 code unit for the Unicode codepoint U+0009.